# How do I use glass pane but also allow a user entering data in a specific UI component but disable all others?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to design tutorials in my cn1 app. I can have an instructor painted on the glass pane to direct a user to enter required data in UI components step by step.

Can I have a glass pane and also let the user enter data in a specific UI component on the form but disable all others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a pointer listener to the parent form and if you want to block an action from propagating you can `consume()` the event. You can get the component at the X/Y location to decide whether the event should be consumed or allowed to proceed.

Edit. This should look roughly like this:

```
Form parentForm = ...;
parentForm.addPointerReleasedListener(ev -> {
    Component cmp = parentForm.getComponentAt(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
    if(!allowCmpEvent(cmp)) {
        ev.consume();
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you clarify "a pointer listener to the parent form"? I can't find it on the cn1 developer guide. Would you provide some samples? I still need a tutor to show some guidance on screen. Can I paint it on the glass pane? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Added a sample to the answer.